# Using && in Windows FileAssociation Action Commandline

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, registry

I can use the `&&` conjunction from within a standard Windows CMD shell to run two commands on the same line as such:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%1" -write_xing 0 -ac 2 -ar 24000 -ab 48k -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%1".mp3 && DEL /Q "%1"
```

- by which I delete the input file after having successfully converted it into mp3 output file using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)

But the same line of code **crashes** when I insert it in to the appropriate RegEdit location e.g.:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\foobar2000.exe\shell\mp3\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe\" -i \"%1\" -write_xing 0 -ac 2 -ar 24000 -ab 48k -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 \"%1\".mp3 && DEL /Q \"%1\" "
```

while it worked fine before I added the trailing `&&` clause. You run it by a right click context menu item.

Is there any way to achieve this preferably  without creating additional BAT/CMD files.  I tried placing `( )` brackets around the entire line but then it seemed to change scope and no longer find the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executed in cmd `&&` is recognized as a command separator, but in registry may be taken as a litteral argument `"&&"`. maybe following can help

```
%ComSpec% /C """C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"" -i ""%1"" -write_xing 0 -ac 2 -ar 24000 -ab 48k -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 ""%1"".mp3 && DEL /Q ""%1"" "
```

EDIT: update from comment

```
CMD /C ("C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%1" -write_xing 0 -ac 2 -ar 24000 -ab 48k -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%1".mp3 && DEL /Q "%1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointer Nahuel - I got it working with a variant on your suggestion: `CMD /C ("C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%1" -write_xing 0 -ac 2 -ar 24000 -ab 48k -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "%1".mp3 && DEL /Q "%1")` - update your answer and I'll give you the tick.